# Print one item or multiple items from Bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, printing, carousel

I am trying to get items to print from a Bootstrap 3.0 carousel. Currently it only prints all the items in a carousel. I have a dropdown for the user to select print options, which are 'Print single item', and 'Print all items'. I can't figure out how to just print a single carousel item, it always prints all the items no matter what.

My Javascript print functionality is:

```js
function PrintSingleLoanReport() {
  var toPrint = document.getElementById('PaymentHistoryOpenItemsReportCarousel');
  $('.item').css("display", "inline");
  var popupWin = window.open("");
  popupWin.document.open();
  popupWin.document.write('<html><title>Payment History & Open Items</title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Content/PrintSingleReport.css"/></head><body onload="window.print()">')
  popupWin.document.write(toPrint.innerHTML);
  popupWin.document.write('</html>');
  popupWin.document.close();
}

function PrintAllLoanReports() {
  var toPrint = document.getElementById('PaymentHistoryOpenItemsReportCarousel');
  $('.item').css("display", "block");
  var popupWin = window.open("");
  popupWin.document.open();
  popupWin.document.write('<html><title>Payment History & Open Items</title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Content/PrintAllReports.css"/></head><body onload="window.print()">')
  popupWin.document.write(toPrint.innerHTML);
  popupWin.document.write('</html>');
  popupWin.document.close();
}
```

The dropdown menu code is:

```html
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="PrintSingleLoanReport(); return false;">Print Single Loan Report</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="PrintAllLoanReports(); return false;">Print All Loan Reports</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

*** UPDATE ***

I was pointed toward finding the solution to this by dn Fer, thank you. 
What I did to solve this issue was get the carousel data, then get the index of the active element. I look for the element by class name, and since their are several 'item' classes to a carousel, i had to pass the index of the current item to 'toPrint'.

```js
function PrintSingleLoanReport() {
  //  This variable contains all kinds of data and methods related to the carousel.
  var carouselData = $("#PaymentHistoryOpenItemsReportCarousel").carousel().data('bs.carousel');
  //  Get current index of active element.
  var currentIndex = carouselData.getItemIndex(carouselData.$element.find('.item.active'));
  var toPrint = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
  $('.item').css("display", "inline");
  var popupWin = window.open("");
  popupWin.document.open();
  popupWin.document.write('<html><title>Payment History & Open Items</title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Content/PrintSingleReport.css"/></head><body onload="window.print()">')
  popupWin.document.write(toPrint[currentIndex].innerHTML);
  popupWin.document.write('</html>');
  popupWin.document.close();
}
```

Comment: In both cases you're getting the PaymentHistoryOpenItemsReportCarousel Element. Shouldn't you get a single carousel item for printing a single item?

Comment: @ dn Fer, I do believe you are correct, and that i should be getting a single carousel item. But i am not sure how to get the active carousel item.

Comment: I believe it gets the class .active  but without your HTML code I can't tell you the element to look for.

Comment: I'm glad you've solved your problem and thank you for the credits you gave me. Too bad you didn't earn enough reputation yet to upvote my comment. ;o)